# VB 6 pass argument As Database to function - type mismtach

Tags: vb6

I try to pass argument to function (Visual Basic 6)

Dim oDB As Database
..
oDB = OpenDatabase(databaseName$)

SampleFunction(oDB)    ' here error type mismatch

..

Function SampleFunction(ByRef oDB As Database)

' oDB.TableDefs("tableName")

End Function

How can I pass this argument correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not located in the Database, but in the call to the SampleFunction:

Either write:

```
Call SampleFunction(oDB)
```

or:

```
SampleFunction oDB
```

or:

```
Dim x
x=SampleFunction(oDB)
```

By the way: you are much better off by first going to sites like [www.vb6.us](http://www.vb6.us) or [visualbasic.freetutes.com](http://visualbasic.freetutes.com/learn-vb6/)

Answer (score 0):

One thing might be that you need to use **Set**

```
Set oDB = OpenDatabase(databaseName$)
```